# How to export the private key from a Salesforce Self Signed cert using PHP or openssl?

Tags: php, openssl, salesforce, self-signed-certificate

I created a Self-Signed cert by following this [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_keys_creating.htm&type=5) I set the private key as exportable but there isn't an export link within the salesforce app (that I can see) so I'm guessing you have to export from the certificate itself. I'm using the [PHP openssl x509 functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.openssl.php) but i can't get it to work. I keep getting `openssl_sign(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a private key...` when I run this code:

```
...
$private_key = openssl_get_privatekey(file_get_contents(env('SALESFORCE_CERT_FILE')));
$s = "";
openssl_sign($header . '.' . $payload, $s, $private_key, "SHA256");
...
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. In salesforce they do have an "export" button that says "Export to Keystore". I was unfamiliar with this so I didn't think to use it. I was looking for export private key or something like that. Turns out you can just following the answer to this [stack exchange question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3779/how-can-i-export-my-private-key-from-a-java-keytool-keystore) to get your private key.

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm that the cert file doesn't have the private key. JKS is the way to go.